# How to add components to layouts using React.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react.rb

I use content_for and partials in my layouts, and I was wondering how to add my React components same way I add partials using [React.rb](http://reactrb.org/).

Thanks.

Comment: Add react component to your partials?

Comment: @HieuPham I meant as I add partials, edited the question, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use `react_component` in place of a partial.

So `<%= react_component "Components::Foo", name: @user.name, rank: @user.rank %>`

would mount the Components::Foo component at this point passing the users name, and rank.

There is no direct equivalent to content_for when bridging between layouts and react.  Instead you would break the view into several component (one for each content_for block) and individually reference them using react_component.

Be aware that you can also directly mount the component from the controller, using the `render_component` method in the controller.